# scope variable evaluates correctly but doesn't reach conditional statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this code in my controller:

```
$rootScope.nodeId = $stateParams.studynodeRef;
Studies.all()
  .then(function(payload) { 
    $scope.studies = payload;
    $scope.study = $filter('filter')(payload, function (d) {
      $scope.id = '"' + $rootScope.nodeId + '"';
      return d.nodeRef === $scope.id;
    })[0]; 
  });
```

`$scope.studies = payload` returns a JSON object array of studies and each study has a unique nodeRef.

In the function I filter out a particular study with the nodeRef `$stateParams.studynodeRef`, however `$scope.study` doesn't return anything.

When I try a particular noderef for return d.nodeRef for instance `return d.nodeRef === "someid"` however, `$scope.id` does not work.

Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: You say `$.scope.id` does not work. What I think you mean is it's not working as you expect. What happens and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Your code actually is `return d.nodeRef === '"someid"'`.

Comment: Right my bad. So when I try {{id}} on a template I do see the id however, for some reason $scope.id never reaches the last line return d.nodeRef === $scope.id

Comment: it might help if you provided a small sample of your payload json

Comment: and it may be worth noting that angular's `$filter('filter')` expects an array as the first argument (not an object)...